# Diagram commutativity with adjoint functor

Tags: category-theory

Suppose I have a diagram 
$A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C = A \rightarrow  D\rightarrow C$ which I would like to commute. I already obtained commutativity for $\mathcal{F}A \rightarrow \mathcal{F}B \rightarrow \mathcal{F}C = \mathcal{F}A \rightarrow  \mathcal{F}D\rightarrow \mathcal{F}C$ where $(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ form an adjunction of functors. I am particularly thinking of a closed monoidal category, with the functors being the tensor product and the internal $hom$ functor.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in general. The problem is essentially whether left adjoints are faithful. For a counterexample to this, look at [abelianization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Abelianization).

Even if you restrict to tensor-hom adjunctions, it is not true in general. Take for example the two morphisms $a,b:\mathbb{Z}/(5)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/5$ such that $a(1)=1$ and $b(1)=-1$. These are equal after tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ (They are both the zero map).